# How to express int array[6] in YAML

Tags: serialization, yaml

I have a type `int arr[6]`, and the value is  `{1,2,3,4,5,6}`. How should I express this data using YAML?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

or

```
- 1
- 2
- 3
- 4
- 5
- 6
```

Answer (score 5):

It throws IllegalArgumentException in my spring application, when I use [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] in application.yaml. However it works when i use 1,2,3,4,5,6

my annotation code is

```
@Value("${app.groupIds}")
private int[] groupIds;
```

Answer (score 4):

You should simply use a list:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```